# Row total for calculated fields using SSRS Report Builder 2.0 over SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a SRSS (2.0) tablix where I need to total the rows at group level (Contract) and DataSet Level (All Contracts)

In the detail rows I have a cell that holds a 'contract cost', a cell holding 'contract term' (months), two cells containing 'contract start date' and 'contract end date' then 12 columns for the months (Apr to Mar) of a financial year.

Each cell in a detail row has an expression that calculates:

```
<if this month is in the contract period then 'contract cost / contract period = result>
```

The results in coloumns are totalled so thet each month has a total expenditure by individual contract and all contracts

But I can't find a way to total the rows. Contracts may start or end at any period through the Financial Year so I need to row-total each detail line.

On the SQL Server 2008 I don't have authority to create tables/views, temp or perm.  Otherwise I'd do that.

Any ideas?

And I'd put up an example but can't seem to get an image uploaded and accepted.

Thanks for looking...even more gratitude for resolving.
Brian

Comment: Can you not Right click on the row grouping and add Total? http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms170712.aspx

Answer (score 0):

you could create a a few variables and have them return the running totals

```
Public Shared TotalProdActual as double 
Public Function AddTotalProdActual(ByVal balance AS double ) AS double 
  TotalProdActual = TotalProdActual + balance 
  return balance 
End Function 

Public Function GetTotalProdActual() 
  return TotalProdActual
End Function
```